Consolidating rows from a table
I have the following table:



UserID1
Amount1
UserID2
Amount2
.....
UserIDN
AmountN



Each row in the table contains unique user IDs with the corresponding amounts. However, the distribution of these unique user IDs across columns is different for different rows (i.e. the same user ID can appear in different columns for different rows), like this:



UserID1
Amount1
UserID2
Amount2
.....
UserIDN
AmountN




1
10
2
15
.....
125
30


2
26
5
17
.....
3
26


125
17
3
22
.....
1
20



.....
I need to sum the Amount values for each identical UserID from all rows and dump these results into the following table:



UserID
Amount



in which each row will contain a unique UserID from the original table and the sum of this UserID's Amounts from all the rows in the original table. For the example above the resulting table will look like:



UserID
Amount




1
30


2
41


3
48


125
47


5
17



What would be the best way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Best way? Would be to correct your database design. You shouldn't ever store multiple values in the same row like that.

Otherwise the solution may depend on the max value of N

How would you suggest to correct the design? And what would be the solution for N = 50?

You normalise it. And add the max N value in your question so its obvious to anyone looking to help.

.. and use 50 select queries, combine them with UNION ALL. You can also use dynamic SQL to loop through but messy.

Concerning your question how to fix the DB structure: This depends on what information you need. If it's sufficient to know which user has which total amount, then only store the userid and the amount and remove all other columns. Update the amount when it changes or just add separate rows. If you really need separate columns for different amounts, then use one column with the userid and different columns for the amounts. Give them better names than Amount1 or Amount28. Then again update the rows or use separate rows rather than separate columns.

How do you update this table? Say user 125 should have Amount 40. Do you write a script which looks for every row unless it finds correct user column? How to you remove a user? Do you shift every column to the left? I would love to meet the designer of this structure to see what makes them tick. Upvoted for sheer panaché

Here is the task I'm solving and why this specific design was chosen (I'm the author of the design, but I'm not a DB developer, so I'm trying to keep the DB part of my project as simple as possible and offload what is reasonable to the application server that speaks with the DB server): I have a big table of users that keeps various user data and one of the fields is the ever changing Amount. Once daily I need to fetch 50 users having the greatest Amount from this big table of users. I save this result to a new row in the table from my question.  Continued below...

After that I need to aggregate 7 and 30 latest rows from this table (i.e. 7 and 30 latest days of results) by user ID, sort the results by Amount and fetch 50 users with greatest aggregate Amount for both 7 and 30 latest days.
TLDR: I have a table of users, each having a constantly changing amount. I need to determine on a daily basis what 50 users had the greatest total amount  over the latest 7 days and over the latest 30 days.

@mikhailitsky, did you have a chance to try the proposed answer(s)?

@YitzhakKhabinsky I'm on my way...

If you are doing this as a one-off, you can use dynamic SQL:
declare @i integer=2, @sql as nvarchar(max)='select userId1 as UserId, Amount1 as Amount from YrTbl';
while @i <= 50 begin
  set @sql = @sql + ' union all' + char(10) + 
             N'select userId' 
                  + cast(@i  as nvarchar(10)) + N', '
                  + 'Amount'
                  + cast(@i  as nvarchar(10)) + N' from YrTbl'
  set @i=@i+1
end;
set @sql=N'select UserId, sum(Amount) as Amount  into #YrNewTable from (' + @sql + ') S1 group by UserId'
exec sp_executesql @sql
--print @sql

For production work careful consideration must be paid to security/performance aspects of dynamic SQL.
Alternative to looping:
declare @sql varchar(max);
set @sql=(SELECT string_agg('select ' + Column_name + ' as UserId, Amount' + substring(column_Name, 7,10) + ' as Amount from YrTbl union all', char(10))
            FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
            WHERE c.TABLE_NAME LIKE '#YrTbl%'
            and Column_Name like 'UserId%')
set @sql='select UserId, sum(Amount) as Amount) from (' 
         + lefT(@sql,len(@sql)-9)
         + ') S1 group by UserId'
exec sp_executesql@sql


Is it possible to traverse the column names and use them in this script, instead of hardcoding them?

İt is possible to loop over the column names in a table but how would we know which columns to use as Id, and which columns to sum? If it is only the number of columns you are after, instead of hardcoding 50 in our example; you can add another variable: declare @NumCols integer=(select count(*) from information_schema.columns where table_name='YrTbl' and column_name like 'UserId%') and use this variable in the WHILE loop criteria.

In my scenario there will always be an even number of columns coming in the user_id + amount pairs, so every first column will always be a user id and every other column will always be an amount.

the second example i added to my answer should work for you

Please try the following solution based on SQL Server's powerful XML and XQuery functionality.
It is generic regardless how many column pairs are across in the table. No need in any dynamic SQL.
The entire magic is based on the mod operator.
Notable points:

1st CROSS APPLY is converting all columns into XML data type.
2nd CROSS APPLY is re-shaping XML into a proper format based on XML attributes.
3rd CROSS APPLY is shredding XML back into relational/rectangular data.
Post CTE SELECT is grouping and summing data.

To feel and see it, here is the first row x value has the following XML:
<root>
  <UserID1>1</UserID1>
  <Amount1>10</Amount1>
  <UserID2>2</UserID2>
  <Amount2>15</Amount2>
  <UserID3>125</UserID3>
  <Amount3>30</Amount3>
</root>

and the y has the following value:
<root>
  <r id="1" amount="10" />
  <r id="2" amount="15" />
  <r id="125" amount="30" />
</root>

The same for each row.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (UserID1 INT, Amount1 INT, UserID2 INT, Amount2 INT, UserID3 INT, Amount3 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (UserID1, Amount1, UserID2, Amount2, UserID3, Amount3) VALUES
(1  , 10, 2, 15, 125, 30),
(2  , 26, 5, 17, 3  , 26),
(125, 17, 3, 22, 1  , 20);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT z.value('@id', 'INT') AS ID
        , z.value('@amount', 'INT') AS Amount
    FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(x)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT x.query('<root>
       {
          for $x in /root/*[position() mod 2 = 1]
          let $pos := count(/root/*[. << $x[1]]) + 1
          return <r id="{$x/text()}" amount="{/root/*[$pos + 1]/text()}"></r>
       }
       </root>')) AS t2(y)
    CROSS APPLY y.nodes('/root/r') AS t3(z)
)
SELECT ID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM rs
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;

Output



ID
Amount




1
30


2
41


3
48


5
17


125
47




Here a fiddle to verify this works as expected: https://dbfiddle.uk/PAqQbWla

One of the options to do it is using UNPIVOT to get your UserID-Amount pairs into rows and then to do aggregation:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a : 
  tbl (UserID1, Amount1, UserID2, Amount2, UserID3, Amount3) AS
    ( Select    1,  10,  2,  15,  125,  30 Union All
      Select    2,  26,  5,  17,    3,  26 Union All
      Select  125,  17,  3,  22,    1,  20
    ),

... create cte (pairs) to transpose columns to rows using UNPIVOT
  pairs as
    ( Select   Case  When UserID Is Null
                     Then LAG(UserID) Over(Partition By PAIR Order By PAIR)
               Else  UserID
               End as UserID, 
               Amount
      From    ( Select    COLUMN_PAIR, Right(COLUMN_PAIR, 1) as PAIR,
                          Case When Left(COLUMN_PAIR, 1) = 'U' Then Amount End as UserID, 
                          Case When Left(COLUMN_PAIR, 1) = 'A' Then Amount Else 0 End as Amount
                From      ( Select *
                            From   ( Select   *  From   tbl ) t
                            UNPIVOT ( Amount 
                                      FOR COLUMN_PAIR IN( UserID1, Amount1, 
                                                          UserID2, Amount2, 
                                                          UserID3, Amount3 )   
                                    ) u 
                         ) u
              ) u
    )

... aggregate (Sum) the amounts and group by UserID
--      M a i n    S Q L : 
Select    UserID, Sum(Amount) as Amount
From      pairs
Group By  UserID
Order By  UserID

/*
UserID  Amount
------  ------
     1      30
     2      41
     3      48
     5      17
   125      47      */

See the fiddle here.

The OP asked: "...And what would be the solution for N = 50?..."

@YitzhakKhabinsky It's either unpivoting 50 pairs or your xml solution. The decision is on OP.
